# Не подключается отдельный файл цсс к хтмл

Tags: css3, html5

[image: Код]

Пробовал разными путями,цсс не подгружается,помогите
Перед style.css ставить "/" бесполезно,в конце закрывать тег при помощи /> тоже не помогает..

Comment: пробовали поставить перед названием / ? `"/style.css"`

Comment: Правая скобка должна быть />   скорее всего компилятор ищет закрывающий тег link

Answer (score -1):

1 способ - используй `<style></style>`
2 способ - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">`

Лучше сделай папку assets, в ней
css, а там положи свой файл, а код html будет такой: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">`